# Spring OAuth2 - when assigning the value to user-name-attribute it gives the error "Missing attribute 'name' in attributes"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Below is my application.yml file

spring:
security:
oauth2:

```
  client:
    registration:
      callback:
        client-id: *******
        client-secret: ******
        client-name: Auth Server
        scope: openid, profile
        provider: custom-provider
        redirect-uri: http://*******/v1/oauth/callback
        client-authentication-method: basic
        authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
    provider:
      custom-provider:
        token-uri: https://*******oauth/nam/token
        jwk-set-uri: https://*******/oauth/nam/keys
        authorization-uri: https://*******/oauth/nam/authz
        user-info-uri: https://*******/oauth/nam/userinfo
        user-name-attribute: name
```

### Below is config file

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

```
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .oauth2Login().redirectionEndpoint()
    .baseUri("/v1/oauth/callback");
    
}
```

### Below is controller file

@Autowired
OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oauth2ClientService;

```
@GetMapping("/v1/oauth/callback")
public String getLoginInfo(Model model, OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {

    OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = oauth2ClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authentication.getName());

    String userInfoEndpointUri = client.getClientRegistration()
        .getProviderDetails()
        .getUserInfoEndpoint()
        .getUri();

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(userInfoEndpointUri)) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + client.getAccessToken()
            .getTokenValue());

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("", headers);

        ResponseEntity<Map> response = restTemplate.exchange(userInfoEndpointUri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class);
        Map userAttributes = response.getBody();
        model.addAttribute("name", userAttributes.get("name"));
    }

    return "loginSuccess";
```

### Getting below error

2021-01-26T10:33:23.611837592Z: [INFO]  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing attribute 'name' in attributes
2021-01-26T10:33:23.611842592Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.DefaultOAuth2User.(DefaultOAuth2User.java:72) ~[spring-security-oauth2-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
2021-01-26T10:33:23.611856692Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.DefaultOAuth2UserService.loadUser(DefaultOAuth2UserService.java:116) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
2021-01-26T10:33:23.611861892Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.userinfo.OidcUserService.loadUser(OidcUserService.java:109) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
2021-01-26T10:33:23.611883692Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.userinfo.OidcUserService.loadUser(OidcUserService.java:66) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
2021-01-26T10:33:23.611888592Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:156) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
2021-01-26T10:33:23.611893092Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
2021-01-26T10:33:23.611897292Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:192) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
2021-01-26T10:33:23.611901792Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
2021-01-26T10:33:23.611905992Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
2021-01-26T10:33:23.611910392Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]

Comment: The issue is with your configuration `user-name-attribute: name`. The UserInfo Response does not contain a `name` attribute. Inspect the UserInfo Response and correct the `user-name-attribute` property to a valid attribute that references the Identifier of the end-user. See the `userNameAttributeName` in the reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-client-registration

Comment: @JoeGrandja Thank you for your help...   After adding the valid user attribute, still not getting the response. Having error on the page...Please let me know how to handle in the controller to get the valid response with the user details

Comment: Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share it via a GitHub repo. This is the most effective method for troubleshooting. I will take a look when you share the repo.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time...The issue got resolved

Comment: @JoeGrandja ...Could you please help me, how we can logout after the authentication is done. Thank you...

Comment: The OAuth support is well documented in the reference. Please refer there first and I'm sure you will find the answer. Here is link to OIDC logout:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.2/reference/html5/#oauth2login-advanced-oidc-logout

Comment: @mathewthomas can you please suggest the root cause and solution as I am facing same issue

Comment: @user2800089  First issue was related to user-name-attribute: name, as the UserInfo Response does not contain a name attribute. So, I have debugged the response and configured "given_name".

Comment: But it was giving another error, which got resolved by removing the context path from the .yml file. Hope this helps you. 
Please print your error message

Comment: @mathewthomas Yes for me also issue was same instead of username , i had given name. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeGrandja I have tried the OIDC logout as per the doc. But logout feature is not working properly. 
Below is the conifg...
httpSecurity
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/",).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated() 
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
        .and().oauth2Login()
        .redirectionEndpoint()
   .baseUri("/api/v1/oauth/callback");

Comment: Below logs is of logout request
.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /logout
o.s.s.w.a.l.SecurityContextLogoutHandler - Invalidated session 711C95115E8943F1F7B55B2CC57D6646
c.u.j.c.EnableEncryptablePropertiesBeanFactoryPostProcessor - Application Event Raised: LogoutSuccessEvent
o.s.s.w.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to /
o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request

Answer (score 0):

Everything is easy: Oauth provider has a response for your service with a provider-specific schema. For example, Github has `login` field, while Google does not have :

```
    15:50:21.459 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.c.WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository - Found SecurityContext 'SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [Andrey Kuleshov], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]], User Attributes: [{email_verified=true, iss=https://accounts.google.com, given_name=Andrey, locale=ru, name=Andrey Kuleshov, exp=2023-07-13T13:50:17Z, family_name=Kuleshov, ...],
```

So with Spring Security you can explicitly set the name of the field where `user-name-attribute` will be taken from:

```
github:
    user-name-attribute: login
```

In your case field `name` is missing in the response of your provider. Just check the user info details.